# Refresh textarea every few seconds that populates from MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, textarea

I'm working on a little PHP MYSQL chat app. I need to refresh the data in the chat window every few seconds without reloading the entire page. I know I have to use Javascript or Jquery to accomplish this but I don't really know them good enough.

Below is the code that creates the chat window and populates it from the database.

Thanks so much, appreciate the help.

```
<textarea id="screen" name="screen" style="width:100%;height:300;resize:none">
    <?php
       $sql="SELECT * FROM `$tbl_5` WHERE advertid='$advertid' ORDER by id ASC";
       $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql);
       while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
       {
            echo $row2[5]."\n";
       }
    ?>
</textarea>
```

EDIT: My attempt using AJAX

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
sendRequest();
function sendRequest(){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
           url: '/chatrefresh.php',
           data: parameters,
           success: function(response){ 
               $('#chatwindow').html(response);
           },
           error: function(response){
               alert(response);
           },
           complete: function() {
               setInterval(sendRequest, 5000);
      }
   });
  };
 });
</script>

<table id="chatwindow" name="chatwindow"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Chatrefresh.php

```
<textarea id="screen" name="screen" style="width:100%;height:300;resize:none">
<?php 
include_once('session.php');
include('config.php');
$advertid=$_SESSION['advertid'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `$tbl_5` WHERE advertid='$advertid' ORDER by id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
 {
    echo $row[5]."\n";
 }
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: You are looking for AJAX, though for chats, websockets are probably better

Comment: jQuery has several built in functions that allow you to perform ajax requests on the fly. They are get, post, and ajax. all you need to do is make the Ajax request to your server and update your html from the response.

Comment: Try to start from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Good luck :)